How to delete all exact element tags in inspect element console with this querySelectorAll method?
think of this as giving a manual of how to do querySelectorAll method to dummies because it is
now dont use terms i understand that actually confuses me just explain but do it thourally please with detail instruction
as long as i am given detail instruction of everything i have to do i can do the task
I have this webpage I saved on my computer that i edited everything i didnt need out of it on inspect element
Im trying to now remove the text inside each profile im following
i found the exact element of each one and their <Div class= their dir= their style= and their bis_skin_checked=
what ever that is, are all the exact
so i figured if i can just find a script to plug into console that deletes or removes all elements like for example delete all A and all A from the wepage are deleted
i could achieve what i want without the tedious work of removing from each one which is 700 by the way
here is the exact entire element
i need every thing on the webpage that has this element to be removed so it disappears off the screen
here is the entire element

for somereason the div class part does not show up on the body so i sent a screenshot
it does however show if you edit my body
so heres it pasted as well
div class="css-146c3p1 r-bcqeeo r-1ttztb7 r-qvutc0 r-37j5jr r-a023e6 r-rjixqe r-16dba41 r-1h8ys4a r-1jeg54m"
dir="auto" style="text-overflow:unset;color:rgb(15,20,25)" bis_skin_checked="1"
i might have resolved it where it will now show up
Anyway someone sent this querySelectorAll method
now its my fault i should have clarified i am not a coder or a scripter i have literally basic novice knowealge of inspect element, elements, css and html
so i will need someone to explain step by step instruction on how to use this method
here it is pasted
function hideMyElements(attributes) {
let selector = attributes.map(attr => [${attr.name}="${attr.value}"]).join('');
document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(elem => {
elem.style.display = "none";
// Or if you want to completly remove the element:
//elem.remove();
});
}
const attributes = [
{name: "bis_skin_checked", value: "1"},
{name: "dir", value: "auto"}
];
hideMyElements(attributes);
this is what they commented with of the method
As long as those attributes you provided are correct ("class", "dir", etc) you can do this pretty easily with native JS.
You can use the "querySelectorAll" method and construct a string selector based on a collection of your attributes. You can then loop through your returned elements with "forEach" to either hide or remove the elements.
You can then construct an array of attribute key-value pairs to feed into the function
